# Using a pageObject for multiple tests in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my project I have created a pageObject named PostPaymentPage for handling payment of various mode like Check, Echeck etc.

In test I do the following:

1. in first test Login to website using LoginPage. A successful login changes browsers url to home page
2. in second test, create an instance of the pageObject named PaymentObj and make a check payment.
3. in third test, again create instance of the pageObject named PaymentEcheck and make a Echeck payment.

Using NUnit when I execute my 1st & 2nd test it works fine
Using NUnit when I execute my 1st & 3rd test it works fine
but if I try to run all the three in single go then third one fails. It fails to locate the page elements(PaymentECheck.A_selectPayMode("ECH"); this line reports could not locate element
).

I created 3 separate test with the idea that Login will be done only once and I can test any payment method in any sequence. Code is attached below

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Threading;
using System.Configuration;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace Billing
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    class MySetUpClass : SeleniumDriver
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void TestSetUp()
        {
            Visit(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseURL"] + "/login.aspx");
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    class PostPayment : SeleniumDriver
    {
        private LoginPage loginpage = new LoginPage(WebDriver);

        private string baseUrl = WebDriver.Url;

        [TestFixtureTearDown]
        public void FixtureTearDown()
        {
            if (WebDriver != null) WebDriver.Quit();
        }

        [Test]
        public void _login()
        {
            loginpage.EnterUserName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loginUserName"]);
            loginpage.EnterPassword(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loginPassword"]);
            loginpage.Login();
            baseUrl = loginpage.getUrl();
            loginpage.printUrl();
        }

        [Test]
        public void MakePaymentByCheck()
        {
            PostPaymentCheckPage PaymentObj = new PostPaymentPage(WebDriver);
            PaymentObj.click_AccountMenu();
            baseUrl = PaymentObj.getUrl();    //Storing this url to be used latter
            PaymentObj.A_click_paymentIcon(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountNo"]);
            PaymentObj.A_selectPayMode("CHK");
            PaymentObj.A_selectPaidBy();
            PaymentObj.A_set_CheckNo("12345");
            PaymentObj.A_set_Comments("Auto QA");
            PaymentObj.A_set_Email(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email"]);
            PaymentObj.A_set_PayAmount("11");
            PaymentObj.A_click_PaymentButton();
            //PaymentObj.A_click_CloseButton();
        }

        [Test]
        public void MakePaymentByECheck()
        {
             PostPaymentCheckPage PaymentECheck = new PostPaymentPage(WebDriver);

            Visit(baseUrl); //webdriver will navigate to this url
            PaymentECheck.A_click_paymentIcon(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["accountNo"]);
            PaymentECheck.A_selectPayMode("ECH");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_eCheckPaidBy();
            PaymentECheck.A_set_PayAmount("11");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_bankName("QA Bank");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_routingNumber("987654321");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_accountNumber("111222");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_stateECH();
            PaymentECheck.A_set_AptNoECH("098");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_CityECH("QA City");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_zipECH("12345");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_CommentsECH("Auto QA");
            PaymentECheck.A_set_EmailECH(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["email"]);
            PaymentECheck.A_click_ECheckPaymentButton();

        }

    }

}
```

Can you please let me know why the third test fails when I try to run all the test in a single go?

Comment: So why doesn't it find the element? `PaymentECheck.A_selectPayMode("ECH");`, fails, why? When it's only run in the full suite, why? Breakpoint it, debug it, what does the page look it *at that point*? Also, it sounds like the `_login` test is not a test, it's a `Setup`. Your `MySetUpClass` isn't used either. Multiple problems with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your tests should be independent of one another, and be able to run together or seperately, in any order, it looks like this is not actually the case. I presume you're using NUnit (judging by your annotations), I am not familiar with NUnit, but I think you should structure your class more like this....

```
[TestFixtureSetUp] 
public void Init()
{ 
    /* Your login functionality. This method is run ONCE, before any [Test] methods */ 
}

[SetUp] 
public void Init()
{ 
    /* Navigate to home page. This method is called before EACH [Test] method, therefore all tests need to expect to start from the same location */ 
}

[Test]
public void MakePaymentByCheck()
{
   /* Navigate to PostPaymentPage and perform test steps */
}

[Test]
public void MakePaymentByECheck()
{
    /* Navigate to PostPaymentPage and perform test steps */
}
```

It's important to note that creating an instance of a Page Object doesn't necessarily mean the browser gets navigated to that page (unless that is what's done in the constructor). As Arran said, debug your code, ensure you are actually on the page you think you should be for each test

Answer (score 0):

After searching about the problem more I found the selenium error 3719 which states

Issue #3719: No longer redirecting console output for Firefox. This
   information was largely unused by anyone, and the implementation had a
   chance to produce deadlocks when reading from the console output stream for
   stdout and stderr.

This was a bug in Selenium 2.39. The new version 2.40 which is released on 19th Feb 2014 has a fix for this issue.

With Selenium 2.40 the problem reported by me is solved